# Exporting mxds into pdfs using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have written a python script to export my mxd into a pdf (not using data driven pages). I am getting the error that my mxd path is incorrect! I have included my script below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# Necessary modules
import arcpy, os, string, sys

# For less complicated scripts -
# these 2 imports are necessary to utilize a simpler method of debugging outher than traceback 
import win32ui, win32con

# example debug message to screen ......
# arcpy.AddMessage("mxd_file = " + str(mxd_file))
# val = win32ui.MessageBox("mxd_file = " + str(mxd_file), "title",
                          #win32con.MB_OKCANCEL)

#Paramaters...

mxdList = string.split(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), ";")
dir = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#Loop thru & take the base name of each MXD selected and append all map pages to a single pdf 
# and save to chosen directory......

for mxdPath in mxdList:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
    name = mxdPath[:-4] + ".pdf"
    file = dir + os.sep + os.path.basename(name)
    ddp = mxd
    ddp.exportToPDF(file, "ALL")

del mxd, file
```

Comment: Have you tried including a message to check 'mxdPath' to ensure it's a valid path?

Comment: Also, can you give an example of how you are calling the script? Are you using fully qualified paths?

Answer (score 6):

I think the comments have addressed your immediate issue, but here are just a few suggestions for writing cleaner, more "Pythonic" code:

1. When choosing names for variables (or, more correctly termed in Python, "identifiers"), avoid using names of [built-in types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#built-in-types) and [functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#built-in-functions). [`file`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) and [`dir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) are examples of these. `name` is not, but it's pretty generic. Try to use descriptive identifiers, not only to avoid naming conflicts, but to help yourself and others better understand your code.
2. Take advantage of the [standard library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/) (and check out [Doug Hellman's PyMOTW site](http://pymotw.com/2/contents.html) for a whirlwind tour). For example, you could use the functions in the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module (see also the [PyMOTW article](http://pymotw.com/2/ospath/) on it) to make your path manipulations more robust and clear to other Python programmers.

   - Instead of:

     ```
     name = mxdPath[:-4] + ".pdf"
     ```

     Use [`os.path.splitext`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext), [`os.extsep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.extsep) and the built-in [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method for string objects (might as well do [`os.path.basename`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) here as well):

     ```
     pdfBaseName = os.path.basename(os.extsep.join([os.path.splitext(mxdPath)[0], "pdf"]))
     ```
   - Instead of:

     ```
     file = dir + os.sep + os.path.basename(name)
     ```

     Use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

     ```
     pdfPath = os.path.join(outputFolder, pdfBaseName)
     ```

     (moved `os.path.basename` to previous line and changed your variable names as well)
3. See [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
4. See [Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html)
5. Use a real Python IDE, like [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with [PyDev](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pydev-python-ide-eclipse). Use their interactive debuggers to step through your code, inspect variables, and generally get a better understanding of what is going on at any moment in your program.