# How to update element text in arcpy.mapping?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, layouts, arcpy, element

I have a problem updating a map element text (named `element1`) in a map document using the following code:

```
a1 = '"' + ("element" + str(1)) + '"'
for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
if elm.name  == a1:
    elm.text = str("new text")
    elm.elementPositionX = 0.6046
    elm.elementPositionY = 6.4636
```

The code above does not update the `element1` with the `new text` value.

It looks like the following part does not work:

```
if elm.name  == a1:
```

Because when using the below hard coded approach:

```
if elm.name  == "element1":
```

It worked, but I need to have it as variable.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: replace <<a1 = '"' + ("element" + str(1)) + '"'>> by a1 =  "element" + str(1) , should work

Comment: `'element1' == "element1" != '"element1"'`

Comment: many thanks for your help - the geogeek's hint worked a trick for me! and thanks Mike - all understood :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to wrap the element name in quotes like you are doing.

You can use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) to do this slightly more cleanly:

```
a1 = "element{0}".format(1)
```

See also my suggestions on general Python tips in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/52701/753).